# Svg height gets reduced on text

Tags: css, svg

I have a heading in H1 tag and inside it there is a span with variable texts and length, i am setting a svg border below it, problem occurs when my orange text is less border height get reduced, I am trying to just manage border width as per text, but height remains same

[image]

In above screenshot check the Design word svg borders height get reduced

Example:

```css
 .header {
    max-width: 1000px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    text-align: center;
}
h1 span {
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iNTY2IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA1NjYgNyIgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj4KPHBhdGggZD0iTTIgMi41NzU4MUM1MC4xNDMxIDEuOTgxODMgMTE5LjM5NyAxLjgzODkyIDE2Ny41ODUgMi4xODY1OUMyNTkuMjIyIDIuODQ3NzMgMzY3LjcwOCA4LjE3MjI3IDU2NCAyLjE4NjU5IiBzdHJva2U9IiM5N0VDQTMiIHN0cm9rZS13aWR0aD0iMyIgc3Ryb2tlLWxpbmVjYXA9InJvdW5kIiBzdHJva2UtbGluZWpvaW49InJvdW5kIi8+Cjwvc3ZnPgo=);
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom;
    display: inline-block;
    color: orange;
}
```

````html
```
  
 <div class="header">
        <h1>Choose from our best designs for <span>Personal Care and Service</span></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="header">
        <h1>Choose from our best designs for <span>Installation, Maintenance and Repair</span></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="header">
        <h1>Choose from our best designs for <span>Architechture and Engineering</span></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="header">
        <h1>Choose from our best designs for <span>Design</span></h1>
 </div>
````

Comment: replace `background-size: 100%;` with `background-size: auto 10px;` where the second parameter is the height you want

Comment: In this case the rounded edges of svg get vanished

Comment: @LS_ its seems to be not working as expected

Comment: I don't think you can achieve that with this approach. You either have fixed height for all lines, which will make the width grow outside of the container, or 100% width, which will make the height adapt based on the container's width.

Answer (score 3):

`vector-effect: "non-scaling-stroke"` is *probably* what you want.

You can refactor this Web Component below back to CSS only.

```js
customElements.define("span-line", class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let strokeWidth = 4;
      let color = (this.getAttribute("color")||"#97ECA3").replace("#","%23");
      let y = 21;
      let svg = `<svg viewBox='0 0 566 24' fill='none' preserveAspectRatio='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>` +
      `<path d='M2 ${y}c48 0 118 0 165 0 92 1 201 6 397 0' stroke-width='${strokeWidth}' ` +
      ` vector-effect='non-scaling-stroke' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' ` +
      ` stroke='${color}'/></svg>`;
      Object.assign(this.style, {
        backgroundImage: `url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,${svg}")`,
        backgroundSize: "100%",
        backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
        backgroundPosition: "left bottom",
        display: "inline-block"
      });
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<h1><span-line>A sentence</span-line></h1>
<h1><span-line>A longer sentence</span-line></h1>
<h1><span-line>A much much much much longer sentence</span-line></h1>
<h1><span-line color="red">Short</span-line></h1>
```

Note: if you need to tweak the SVG path, use: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/#